# Mysql max date within a subquery

Tags: mysql

i cant work out how to get this subquery working to get the latest date for the row.

```
SELECT Thread_Heading.*, Thread_Articles.*, Thread_ArticlesPost.* 
FROM Thread_Heading 
LEFT JOIN Thread_Articles 
    ON Thread_Articles.Thread_Article_Head_id=Thread_Heading.Thread_Head_id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Thread_ArticlesPost.* 
    FROM Thread_ArticlesPost 
    ORDER BY Thread_ArticlePost_DT DESC
) Thread_ArticlesPost 
    ON  Thread_ArticlesPost.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id=Thread_Articles.Thread_Article_id  
WHERE Thread_Head_Level = '5' 
GROUP BY Thread_Heading.Thread_Head_id 
ORDER BY Thread_ArticlePost_DT DESC
```

I need to order the article post date by the latest post for each Thread article.
Fairly new to sql and php i just cant work this one out any help would be appreciated.

T

```
ABLE: Thread_Heading | 
Thread_Head_id
Thread_Head_Name
Thread_Head_Type
Thread_Head_Creator
Thread_Head_Date
Thread_Head_Level

TABLE: Thread_Articles | 
Thread_Article_id
Thread_Article_Head_id
Thread_Article_Creator
Thread_Article_DT
Thread_Article_Level
Thread_Article_Type
Thread_Article_Title

TABLE: Thread_ArticlesPost | 
Thread_ArticlePost_id
Thread_ArticlePost_Head_id
Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
Thread_ArticlePost_Creator
Thread_ArticlePost_DT
Thread_ArticlePost_Level
Thread_ArticlePost_Type
Thread_ArticlePost_Title
Thread_ArticlePost_Content
```

I need to display the date like so:

```
Head Name | Article title | ORDER BY LATEST ArticlePost DT | ArticlePost Creator
```

The reason i used left joins was to get the left data even if there are no article or article replys.

Appreciate the help.

Have used this to display data Thanks to Blue

SELECT *
FROM
    ( SELECT th.Thread_Head_Name,
      ta.*, 
      tp1.maxdate,
      tp2.*
    FROM Thread_Heading th 
    LEFT JOIN Thread_Articles ta 
    ON th.Thread_Head_id = ta.Thread_Article_Head_id 
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
    SELECT max(Thread_ArticlePost_DT) maxDate,
        Thread_ArticlesPost.* 
        FROM Thread_ArticlesPost
        GROUP BY Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
    ) tp1 
        ON  tp1.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id=ta.Thread_Article_id
    LEFT JOIN Thread_ArticlesPost tp2 
        ON tp1.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id = tp2.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id 
      AND tp1.maxdate = tp2.Thread_ArticlePost_DT
    WHERE th.Thread_Head_Level = '5'
    ORDER BY tp1.maxdate DESC) m 
GROUP BY Thread_Head_Name
ORDER BY Thread_ArticlePost_DT DESC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your full table schemas you will want do something similar to this:

```
SELECT th.*, ta.*, tp.* 
FROM Thread_Heading th
LEFT JOIN Thread_Articles ta
    ON th.Thread_Head_id = ta.Thread_Article_Head_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT max(Thread_ArticlePost_DT) maxDate, Thread_ArticlesPost.* 
    FROM Thread_ArticlesPost 
    GROUP BY Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
) Thread_ArticlesPost tp
    ON  tp.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id=ta.Thread_Article_id  
WHERE Thread_Head_Level = '5' 
GROUP BY th.Thread_Head_id 
ORDER BY tp.maxdate DESC
```

Based on your edit the following should return the data you want:

```
SELECT th.Thread_Head_Name, 
  ta.Thread_Article_Title,
  tp1.maxdate,
  tp2.Thread_ArticlePost_Creator
FROM Thread_Heading th
LEFT JOIN Thread_Articles ta
    ON th.Thread_Head_id = ta.Thread_Article_Head_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT max(Thread_ArticlePost_DT) maxDate, 
      Thread_ArticlesPost.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
    FROM Thread_ArticlesPost 
    GROUP BY Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
) tp1
  ON  tp1.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id=ta.Thread_Article_id  
LEFT JOIN Thread_ArticlesPost tp2
  ON tp1.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id = tp2.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
  AND tp1.maxdate = tp2.Thread_ArticlePost_DT 
WHERE th.Thread_Head_Level = '5' 
ORDER BY tp1.maxdate DESC
```

Edit #2, based on your comments, I think the below query should resolve any remaining issues:

```
SELECT th.Thread_Head_id,
  th.Thread_Head_Name,
  ta.Thread_Article_Title,
  tp.Thread_ArticlePost_Creator,
  tap.MaxPostDate
FROM Thread_Heading th 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT max(ta.Thread_Article_DT) MaxArticleDate, 
    ta.Thread_Article_Head_id,
    max(tp.Thread_ArticlePost_DT) MaxPostDate
  FROM Thread_Articles ta
  LEFT JOIN Thread_ArticlesPost tp
    ON ta.Thread_Article_id = tp.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
  GROUP BY Thread_Article_Head_id
) tap
  ON th.Thread_Head_id = tap.Thread_Article_Head_id 
LEFT JOIN Thread_Articles ta
  ON tap.Thread_Article_Head_id = ta.Thread_Article_Head_id
  AND tap.MaxArticleDate = ta.Thread_Article_DT
LEFT JOIN Thread_ArticlesPost tp
  ON tap.MaxPostDate = tp.Thread_ArticlePost_DT
WHERE th.Thread_Head_Level = '5'
ORDER BY MaxPostDate desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0009/120)

Comment: Sorry i could not get this to work, not very good with sql i will update the post above with my tables

Comment: Hi Blue quick reply, says there is an error 'tp1 ON tp1.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id=ta.Thread_Article_id LEFT JOIN T' at line 14

Comment: Hi Blue, i hate being a pain this works ok but i need to group the Thread_heading. It lists all Thread_heading ie there are two articles in Thread_heading but i need it to display just the latest Thread_heading by the latest article post date.

Comment: I did try to add GROUP BY GROUP BY th.Thread_Head_Name, however this seems to come back to my never ending problem of the need to order by before group by which i cant do :(

Comment: @CarlWaddington please create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the tables and some sample data. At this point it would be guesswork without seeing more details

Comment: Hi Blue, sorry went to lunch. i created this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a29/1/0 i need it to just display the Thread Title once as if it was grouped by THREAD_HEAD_NAME so in the example it should only list Test Thread, Recruitment, Test Discussion15. Test Thread and recruitment have two atricles and both have replys/Posts Test discussion has two articles but no posts/replys.

Comment: Hi Blue i think i got it, i want to say a massive thankyou to you :D i dont fully understand sql and especially what you created i assume ta tp are alias for teh tables and its just aboutthe logic. i need to run more tests with more info that sql fiddle was great but would allow many chars to test with. i will put the update in my post. could you let me know if it is ok but i will mark as answered Kind regards, Carl

Comment: @CarlWaddington I am glad I could help. If you hard a hard time understanding joins then you should review [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). It comes in handy.

Comment: Hi Blue I couldnt get it to work this is my data with your query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0009/49 but it needs to display like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0009/66 however it is not showing the latest date :(

Comment: part of the problem appears to be that there are multiple articles for each head, which article do you want to return the most recent article and most recent post?

Comment: Most recent post is what i am trying to go for, i could create you an account to show you the data if needed

Comment: @CarlWaddington please see my edit, here is a new [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0009/120) demo

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have a `GROUP BY` clause outside side your post are already grouped on the subquery based on your latest post. Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM    Thread_Heading a
            LEFT JOIN Thread_Articles b
                ON b.Thread_Article_Head_id = a.Thread_Head_id
            LEFT JOIN Thread_ArticlesPost c
                ON c.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id = b.Thread_Article_id 
            LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT      Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id, MAX(Thread_ArticlePost_DT) maxDate
                FROM        Thread_ArticlesPost 
                GROUP BY    Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id
            ) d ON  d.Thread_ArticlePost_Article_id = b.Thread_Article_id AND
                    c.Thread_ArticlePost_DT = d.maxDate
WHERE       Thread_Head_Level = '5' 
-- GROUP BY a.Thread_Head_id 
ORDER BY    Thread_ArticlePost_DT DESC
```

Comment: This kind of works but does not display the correct rows i am looking for i will update the post above with the tables i have and what data needed to display.

Comment: @CarlWaddington consider using a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for this information, it is very helpful

Comment: I also needed to group by as i just want to show the latest Thread Article by latest date of article post